# Как не закрывая terminal перевести фокус в рабочую область файла?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, webstorm, clion

Для открытия терминала имеется  `alt-f12`. Для перехода обратно приходится закрывать терминал той же командой. Было бы удобно перевести фокус в рабочую область не закрывая терминал горячей клавишей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в окне терминала действует какое-то отдельное пространство хоткеев и большинство обычных в нём приводят к другим результатам. Например, Ctrl + Tab не открывает Switcher, а просто вводит символ табуляции.

На дефолтных настройках сработает следующее сочетание: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> (два раза нажимаем <kbd>2</kbd>, не отпуская <kbd>Alt</kbd>)

Первый <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> открывает окно Favorites, второй закрывает и возвращает курсор в окно редактора.

Аналогичный трюк проходит с цифрами  6 (TODO), 7 (Structure), 9 (Version Control). Но там открываются окна большего размера, что больнее бьёт по глазам. Favourites по умолчанию - самое маленькое.

Вместо второго нажатия цифры можно жать <kbd>Esc</kbd>, результат тот же, но немного медленнее.